# Add/Enable cipher from SSLv3 (DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA) to TLS 1.2 in Node JS TLS

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, rsa, tls1.2

I have a medical device (client) that I have no control over. When an event happens on that device (client) it connects to my server via tls v1.2 to pass data. The error that I have is "no shared cipher".

> [Error: 3160:error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:openssl\ssl\statem\statem_srvr.c:1419:
>   ]

After long investigation it looks like the client cipher suite is not supported in node js 10.9.0. I tried to overwrite default ciphers (DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA. see code below) and the change is taken in consideration because I tried to connect with openssl s_client and fails as it does not support the ciphers. If I set the ciphers to ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA openssl s_client connects. If I do openssl ciphers -sslv3 in the list I see the DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA and DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA. But the client does not connect.

**The connection handshake**
[image: Wireshark tls negociation]

**My Server code:**

```js
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

tls.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA';

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\cert\\private-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\cert\\cert.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
    console.log('server connected',
        socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');

    socket.write('welcome!\n');
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.on('tlsClientError', (error, tlsSocket) => {
    console.log(error);
});

server.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('server bound', 8011);
});
```

**Openssl s_client**

ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
[image: openssl supported cipher]

ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
[image: openssl unsupported cipher]

**How can I add or workaround this old ciphers ?**

**Edit new response:**
[image: Handshake pass]

** New options **

```
const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/sentinel-private-key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/sentinel-cert.pem'),
dhparam: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/dhparams.pem'),
ca:  [fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/ca-cert.ca')],
rejectUnauthorized: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client requires that your server supports perfect forward secrecy using DHE based ciphersuites. In order for that to happen you need to configure your server with appropriate DH parameters.

First you must generate your parameters, e.g.:

```
 openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
```

Next you need to configure your application to use them. Instructions for doing this in Nodes.js are available here:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/tls.html#tls_perfect_forward_secrecy

Comment: Thank you, how did you know the client wanted forward secrecy ?
Now the handshake happens, server response hello done, then client responds with 
Internal Error 80, I added a client CA that from a p12 I could generate on client via web interface. Now I get: Certificate Unknown (46). Maybe is because I use Self signed ?

Comment: You can see in your wireshark dump of the ClientHello that the only two cipersuites that are offered are DHE ones. A key feature of DHE (and ECDHE) based ciphersuites is perfect forward secrecy. WRT to your other problem most likely the self signed certificate you are using is not trusted by the client.